# How to get mail id from google drive android

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I have tried with Plus Api and in tried below code.For Plus.APi it was deprecated.So i tried below code.I got intent data as null.I cant able to get google drive selected account mail id.Pls Help to solve this issue?

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {

    if(context!=null)
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(context, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);

    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION:
                if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (data != null) && (data.getExtras() != null)) {
                    String email = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    LogUtil.error("Email", email);
                }
                break;

}
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Here i got intent data as null

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the [current user using the app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people), use the [`GoogleSignInResult.getSignInAccount`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInResult#getSignInAccount()) method to request profile information for the currently signed in user.

You can call the getSignInAccount method after the sign-in intent succeeds.

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
String personId = acct.getId();
Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
```

## NOTE

> For additional profile data that might be available, see [GoogleSignInAccount](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount). Note that any of the profile fields can be null, depending on which scopes you requested and what information the user's profile includes.

Hope this helps.